# Spring Boot on AWS EKS API limit

Tags: spring-boot, rest, architecture, amazon-eks

I need to design a solution able to process avg 150k requests per day.
I was thinking to expose a REST API from a Spring Boot App running on AWS EKS (current tech approved from CTO), but I'm wondering about the limits.
Is there a knowledge base where I can read of any cap for such scenario (API limit for Spring boot app on EKS considering the pod replicas)?

If this would not work, how would you do that? Was thinking my customer can write on a Kafka queue where my Spring Boot app will read (streaming approach).

The goal is to take requests from my customer app and forward them to my backend system that is gonna do its processes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason why it wouldn't work, EKS is a service that provides Kubernetes as a service, so as long as you get the required resources, the performance of the app depends directly on the application.

150K requests per day is around 1.7 requests per second, which is definitely a manageable volume (of course, depends on the logic your app has)